# Using dart sass implementation, grunt-sass is not compiling the css file without throwing an error

Tags: css, sass, dart, gruntjs

Here is my grunt-sass declaration.

```
 sass: {
   site: {
     options: {
       implementation: 'dart-sass',
       style: 'compressed',
       noCache: true
     },
     dist: {
       files: {
         'dist/css/jk.css' : 'src/sass/jk.scss'
       }
     }
   }
 },
```

When I run grunt, or grunt triggers on the watch clause, I get this output.

```
 Running "sass:site" (sass) task
```

The file "dist/css/jk.css" is never created. I get no other output from Grunt. If I run sass from the command line, the file completes without any trouble.

I'm not sure why it's failing, as it's failing silently. If nothing else, I'd love to know how to enable verbose failures.

UPDATE. Tried running grunt with -v, this is the output.

```
 Running "sass:site" (sass) task
 Verifying property sass.site exists in config...OK
 File: [no files]
 Options: precision=10, implementation="dart-sass", style="compressed", noCache
 undefined
```

It looks like I'm not declaring the files correctly. I'm quite certain the paths are correct. If I run sass from the command line with the same paths it succeeds as expected.

Comment: Have you ran your grunt task with the [`--verbose`](https://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#verbose-v) flag?

Comment: Just tried that. It didn't give me much more info. It just gave me an "undefined" statement.

Comment: I've made more projects with the -v flag. I haven't fixed the issue but I'm getting more useful errors now.

Comment: Can you share your `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json`?

Comment: I've written a more specific question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196332/using-grunt-sass-to-compile-node-sass-i-get-the-error-fatal-error-the-origin

Answer (score 0):

Adding -v or --verbose has returned errors. I'm still not able to compile sass, but the issue of the missing errors is resolved.